# Trying to save image in Flask but it keeps returning None

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

I have used a very similar way to save profile pics for Users and it works but for Posts it doesn't. keeps returning None.
When I upload the image file in the create post page, the file seems to be uploaded but when I hit post button it becomes None. Not sure where it messed up. The path is correct. I even tried switching the function and directory for profile pics since that worked but it doesn't.

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='post', passive_deletes=True)
    likes = db.relationship('Like', backref='post', passive_deletes=True)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post(\"{self.title}\", \"{self.date_posted}\")"

class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    content = TextAreaField('Content', validators=[DataRequired()])
    image_file = FileField('Post picture', validators=[DataRequired(), FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
    submit = SubmitField('Post')

def save_post_picture(form_picture):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_picture.filename)
    picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join('static/post_images', picture_fn)
    output_size = (125, 125)
    i = Image.open(form_picture)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.save(picture_path)
    return picture_fn

@app.route("/post/new", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def new_post():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print('$ok')
        picture_file = save_post_picture(form.image_file.data)
        post = Post(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, user_id=current_user.id, image_file=picture_file)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        print('works')
        flash('Your post has been created!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('create_post.html', title='New Post', form=form, legend='New Post')

<div class="form-group">
                <label for="image_file" class="form-control-label">Image</label>
                {{ form.image_file(class="form-control-file") }}
                <small>Please make sure the file type is either jpg or png.</small>
                {% if form.image_file.errors %}
                    {% for error in form.image_file.errors %}
                        <small><span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span></small>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %} 
            </div>
```

Comment: do u have a correct permission for your uploading folder ?

Comment: Yes. I thought that was the case so I tried it with other directory for profile pictures (because uploading profile pic was successful) but it still doesn't work.